# Query to copy 5 numeric characters from a string to a separate column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In a specific column in my database, I have a lot of strings like

```
sometext sometext 12345 some more text 33 
some 12345 text then some random characters 12-13
text text text 3 text
```

Now I'm looking for a way to copy the sets of 5 numeric characters into a separate column. I've already narrowed down my selection with

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP '[0-9]{5}'
```

But that doesn't isolate the 5 numeric characters. Is there any way I can copy the 5 numeric characters, if present, and NULL if not present (like in the third row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (`text` varchar(49));

INSERT INTO table2 (`text`)
VALUES
    ('sometext sometext 12345 some more text 33'),
    ('some 12345 text then some random characters 12-13'),
    ('text text text 3 text');
```

Query:

```
select
t.text,
substring_index(substring_index(t.text, ' ', n.number), ' ', -1) as 'extracted_number'
from
table2 as t,
(select 1 as 'number' union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6  union select 7 union select 8)  as n
where 
t.text REGEXP '[0-9]{5}'
and substring_index(substring_index(t.text, ' ', n.number), ' ', -1) REGEXP '^[0-9]{5}$'
```

Output:

```
text                                                extracted_number
some 12345 text then some random characters 12-13   12345
sometext sometext 12345 some more text 33           12345
```

You can replace `select 1 as 'number' union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6  union select 7 union select 8` with table filled with numbers. Greatest number should be equal to maximum number of words in a row.

If you could use MariaDB instead of MySQL then you could use a [sequence](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/) to replece numbers table or even use 
[REGEXP_INSTR](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_instr/) (requires MariaDB 10.0.5 or higher) instead of string functions.

UPDATE:

Above query will extract **all** 5 digit numbers from given text - not just the first one.

Comment: Close! The only catch here seems to be that if the number is between brackets like (12345), or when there's another 5 character string like '(12345) (abcde)', it also copies the brackets, and in the last case the other 5 character string too. Is there a way to isolate just the 5 numeric characters and nothing else?

Comment: @EsVee, I've corrected REGEXP in my query from `[0-9]{5}` to `^[0-9]{5}$` so now numbers in brackets are ignored and your requirement of 5 numeric characters is fulfilled.

Comment: The output looks much cleaner now. It would be even better if the numeric values between brackets were not ignored, but copied without their brackets. Is that possible? :)

Comment: @EsVee, yes, it is possible. Modify REGEXP so it is matching numbers in in optional brackets and then remove brackets using `REPLACE`.

Comment: @EsVee, I don't want to create offtopic content in above answer so you can view query for extracting numbers in brackets here: http://pastebin.com/MyShCFKU

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports REGEX only for filtering results. It doesn't let you manipulate the strings like some other string functions (i.e. CONCAT) To get the numbers from the strings you have to use some other language you're comfortable with that supports regex string manipulations and MySQL connections (i.e. PHP, Java, Python etc.) and then INSERT them with the values you've got. Of course you can use the query you already have to narrow down the number of records to work with:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP '[0-9]{5}'
```

Comment: The above answer is correct, save the result of the query into a variable PHP: `$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP '[0-9]{5}'");` and then insert those results into the desired table.